# Bitcoin Blocks Date not coherent?

Tags: blockchain.info, block, script

I was taking data from the BTC Blockchain with a custom script. 
I found something really weird.

Block nr. 24668 was created at 2009-10-09 23:02:57

Block nr. 24669 was created at 2009-10-10 00:15:48

Block nr. 24670 was created at 2009-10-09 23:15:43

Now tell me, how it's possible that block 24670 is 'younger' than the 24669?
I already checked and all the blockchain explorer websites show exactly this data.

Thank you for your attention,

Mattia

Comment: See this: ["Why don't the timestamps in the block chain always increase?
"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/915/why-dont-the-timestamps-in-the-block-chain-always-increase)